# Set docx properties using library .docx

Tags: asp.net, docx, properties-file, novacode-docx

How to set properties like title, author, subject for a file created with docx library for .net ?

[docx](https://docx.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DocX project that you provided appears to be able to easily access the metadata properties that you are referring to and can do so quite easily by using the `CoreProperties` property as seen below :

```
// Load your Document
var wordFile = Novacode.DocX.Load(@"your-docx-file-path");
// Access Metadata properties
var props = wordFile.CoreProperties;
```

The issue here is that this collection of properties is read only, so you won't be able to easily change them. However, you may be able to take a look at what the values look like and attempt to add one manually :

[image: An Example of DocX Exposed Properties]

So if you wanted to update the title property (clearly named `dc:title`), you would simply need to add a new Core Property (via the `AddCoreProperty()` method) that matched that same name and then save the file to persist the changes :

```
// Load your Document
var wordFile = DocX.Load(@"your-docx-file-path");
// Update Metadata
wordFile.AddCoreProperty("dc:title", "Example Title");
wordFile.Save();
```

After doing this, you should be able to re-open the file and see that your changes reflected :

[image: Look the dc:title Attribute Changed!]

As you can see the `dc:title` property is now set to "Example Title" as per the example code above.