# How to remove the Related People (Author and Modified By) property of Word file using Xceed in C#

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, xceed, xceed-datagrid

I am using the Xceed library to create a word file. Now I want to remove the Related People (Author and Modified By) property of the word document.

Here is my code:

```
using Xceed.Words.NET;
using Xceed.Document.NET;
using Image = Xceed.Document.NET.Image;
using Paragraph = Xceed.Document.NET.Paragraph;
using Formatting = Xceed.Document.NET.Formatting;
using Font = Xceed.Document.NET.Font;
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, this can be done by adding the `AddCoreProperty` as below:

```
// Load your Document
var doc = DocX.Load(@"your-docx-file-path");
// Access Metadata properties
var props = doc.CoreProperties;
// Update Metadata
doc.AddCoreProperty("cp:lastModifiedBy", "");
doc.AddCoreProperty("dc:creator", "");
doc.Save();
```

[Set docx properties using library .docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36405511/set-docx-properties-using-library-docx)